# Trouble Installing Breach Browser

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I have downloaded breach on my Linux virtualization in Parallels, but I can't seem to get it to run. I have done:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
cd <the breach download directory>
CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox ./breach
```

When I do the above, I get an error:

```
<directory>/__AUTO_UPDATE_BUNDLE__/exo_browser/exo_browser: error while loading shared libraries: libharfbuzz.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by installing the missing library:

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz0b
```

Comment: It is unable to locate that package. Do I need to do the following?

    sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz.so.0

Comment: it probably means that you're not running at least 14.04 (this package is available only for 14.04 and 14.10 so far, see http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libharfbuzz0b)

Comment: That makes sense, although I tried it on 14.04 and it didn't work there either.